# This site can’t provide a secure connectionlocalhost sent an invalid

Tags: asp.net-core

I have web app runnning in .NET Core 3.01 in Window Server 2016. Then I migrated it to .NET 6. I have already installed dotnet-runtime-6.0.5-win-x64 and aspnetcore-runtime-6.0.5-win-x64 in Window Server 2016. But when I run the web app at https://localhost:44362/swagger/index.html, I got this error

> This site can’t provide a secure connectionlocalhost sent an invalid
> response. Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

It works in my local machine at https://localhost:44362/swagger/index.html

I think this could be due to me using https. So I tried to use without https. But I got error

> This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web
> address: http://localhost:41487/swagger/index.html HTTP ERROR 404

This is my `launchSettings.json`

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:41487",
      "sslPort": 44362
    }
  },
```

Comment: Did you try with the non-ssl port 41487 taken from your config?

Comment: @daniel, yes i do.

Comment: I think I should be installing hosting bundle, dotnet-hosting-6.0.5-win.exe instead of the dotnet 6 runtime , right?

Comment: I solved it already. By default, swagger is set for development only.